# getting error Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name

Tags: windows, api, wso2, typeerror, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to publish API in wso2 API Manager. But I am using basic security with my authorization key. I am getting a type error: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name. I tried to change the swagger file. But didn't get the required response.

Comment: Can you please post more details? Error logs, steps followed, etc

Comment: We have our rest API with a header authorization key. We are trying to publish this API from the wso2 API manager. I chose to design a new rest API.

adding some changes

1. Adding header authorization key 

2. in the resource, added query parameter

I tried out this API in the developer portal and added the query parameter. I got three error 

one error in the curl command "Bearer Undefined."
Type error: failed to execute 'fetch' on 'window' invalid name
in postman, invalid credential, make your API invocation call have a header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to send a header to your backend through APIM, you have define it as a header under resources in the Publisher portal.

However, if the name of your header is Authorization you will have to use some sort of a mediation to send this to your backend. For example,

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="KeyExchange">
    <property name="Custom" expression="get-property('transport', 'Custom')"/>
    <property name="Authorization" expression="get-property('Custom')" scope="transport"/>
    <property name="Custom" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
</sequence>
```

If you add the above to your in-sequences, you will have to send a header called Custom with the key you need to send to the backend. Then APIM will replace this Custom header with Authorization header when sending the request out from APIM.

If you have enabled Basic auth for your API created in APIM, you need to follow [1] to invoke the API.